# Find object from list that has attribute equal to some value and also get the next object after

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-itertools

I am able to find a object that its attribute equals to some value. But I would like to also get the object after that from a list (and also if the found object is the last in list, the next object after that should be the first object). Something like:

```
from pprint import pprint

class User(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

users = []
users.append(User("Peter"))
users.append(User("James"))
users.append(User("John"))

#   find object that has attribute name equal to James
pprint(vars([user for user in users if user.name == "James"][0]))
```

And the output from pprint line prints:

```
{'name': 'James'}
```

That is correct.

I would like to ask you how to get the next object after `"James"` and also if I would search for `"John"` the next object after `"John"` should be returned `"Peter"`. Suggestions?

I also tried with `itertools`, but I cannot get the next element if the found element is last:

```
from itertools import enumerate
_i = next(i for i, user in enumerate(users) if (user.name == "John"))
print users[_i + 1] #this is not working
```

I could add if condition to change the counter before operation `[_i+1]` but I would like to know if there is more smoother solution to this?

Comment: You're missing a closing `)` on the second line of your itertools example. Unrelated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle the last element, you can use modulo: `index % len(users)`.

Here is one way:

```
def find_after_name(users, name):
    for i, user in enumerate(users):
        if user.name == name:
            return users[(i+1) % len(users)]
```

Another option would be to `zip` the list with a shifted copy of the list. `deque.rotate()` is useful for such shifting:

```
from collections import deque
def find_after_name(users, name):
    users2 = deque(users)
    users2.rotate(-1)
    for user1, user2 in zip(users1, users2):
        if user1.name == name:
            return user2
```

Comment: need a way to return an error: ValueError like list.index() or return None

Comment: @Harvey None is returned (implicitly) if the loop is exhausted

Comment: @shx2 Can you explain in a word or two how this expression is interpreted in python `(i+1) % len(users)`? Do `deque` and `deque.rotate()` store modified data to new memory space as in real problem I have to process quite a lot of data this way  and it would not be the most efficient way or am I wrong?

Comment: @avstenit, right, the second solution is an attempt to be more elegant (using a more "pythonic" loop), but is slower, because it uses a second "duplicate" container. As to the modulo, it takes advantage of the fact `n%n=0`, and that `k%n=k` if `0<=k<n`.

Comment: @shx2: thanks for the reminder about None. Also, I added a more pythonic solution which avoids additional storage. It uses itertools.dropwhile() as an index() method.

Comment: @shx2 is it possible to change `return users[(i+1) % len(users)]` that it will return `i`-th and `i+1` user object in a list with modifying the expression `(i+1) % len(users)`?  I tried with this `(i, i+1) % len(users)`, but got some errors.

Comment: Just return a tuple where the first value is `user`, like: `return ( user, users[(i+1) % len(users)] )`

Answer (score 1):

Since you've chosen to use OOP, why not implement a UserList class inherited from built-in list class?

```
class User(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "User('{0}')".format(self.name)


class UserList(list):
    def find(self, name):
        for k, user in enumerate(self):
            if user.name == name:
                return k, user

    def next_to(self, name):
        """get user next to the one of name (e.g. 'James')"""
        index, user = self.find(name)
        next_to_index = self.get_next_to_index(index)
        return self[next_to_index]

    def get_next_to_index(self, index):
        next_to_index = index + 1
        if next_to_index == len(self):
            # meaning index is already the last element, need to reset index
            next_to_index = 0
        return next_to_index


users = UserList()
users.append(User("Peter"))
users.append(User("James"))
users.append(User("John"))

print users.find('James')
print users.next_to('James')
print users.next_to('John')
```

Output:

```
(1, User('James'))
User('John')
User('Peter')
```

Comment: Well the initial data is in matrix form, and than I also build objects from it (the real problem is about `class Node` not `class User` - it is used just for simple example). So I have to decide which way to go OOP or noOOP. The goal is not to add too much additional methods to the `class User`

Comment: ok, your description is not very clear to me, but it's good that seems you've already made a decision.

Answer (score 1):

For kicks, I wanted to see if there was an itertools solution:

```
from itertools import dropwhile
def find_after_name(users, name):
    for i, _ in dropwhile(lambda eu: eu[1].name != name, enumerate(users)):
        return users[(i+1) % len(users)]
```

Note: There really should be a list.index(value, key=None) method where key is like the key argument to list.sort(). Then you could do something like this:

```
index = users.index("John", key=lambda u: u.name)
```

Comment: I was also thinking to use something like `cycle` from `itertools`, but something was not working as I planned.

Comment: @avstenit: some on the #python IRC channel pointed out that this is the correct way to do it: `next(i for i,o in enumerate(list) if value == key(o))`

Answer (score 1):

Solution extending list class:

```
class extended_list(list):
    def index(self, value, key=None):
        if key is None:
            return super().index(self, value)
        try:
            return next(i for i,o in enumerate(self) if value == key(o))
        except StopIteration:
            raise ValueError("{} is not in list".format(repr(value)))


def find_after_name(users, name):
    i = extended_list(users).index(name, key=lambda u: u.name)
    return users[(i+1) % len(users)]
```